# How do I get the minimum measure value excluding a dimension?

Tags: ssas, mdx, measure

I am trying to create a calculated member that will give me the minimum value of another measure excluding a dimension.

So, for example, I have a Product and Location dimension. I have a measure that gives me the first time that product was every sold at that location. I want another measure that will give the first time that product was sold at any location (so same dimension usage except I'm not taking the location into account).

How do I go about this?
Would I use something like `currentmember` for the dimensions except the location dimension?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
([Location].[Location].[All],[Measures].[MinDate])
```

[Location].[Location].[All] will help you to ignore the current location and scan through all locations.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks. So because I have the aggregation type set to MIN, I am basically just grabbing the value of the All Member. So with MDX, if you don't include other dimensions in the tuple, does it use the context of the current member to fill in the blanks? For example, on a row by row basis, because I haven't included any member for the product dimension, does it just use the member of the current interated row?

Comment: If you don't include any member from [Product].[Product] hierarchy, it means the [Product].[Product].DefaultMember will be used. By default your [Product].[Product].DefaultMember == [Product].[Product].[All]. However, you can set DefaultMember by your own.